# Serialize a non-serializable custom object from a nuget package and store it in SQLite database

Tags: c#, xamarin, serialization, sqlite, nuget-package

I'm working with some highly custom objects from a nuget package that I need to store in the local SQLite db using Xamarin. I tried using this code

```
public static byte[] Serialize(ComplexType c)
    {
        byte[] arrayData;

        using(MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {               
            BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            formatter.Serialize( stream, c );
            arrayData = stream.ToArray();
            stream.Close();
        }

        return arrayData;
    }

public static ComplexType Deserialize(byte[] arrayData)
    {
        ComplexType c;

        using(MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            stream.Write( arrayData, 0, arrayData.Length );
            stream.Seek( 0, SeekOrigin.Begin );
            BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            c = (ComplexType) formatter.Deserialize( stream );
        }

        return c;
    }
```

to serialize and store the object then retrieve it and deserialize it. It seems like it worked fine to do the serialization but now it turns out that the object is not marked serializable. I can't add the `SerializableAttribute` property to it because it's from a nuget. I tried editing the object definition in the nuget but of course it's locked.

Is there any easy way to pull off serializing an object not marked serializable or perhaps some other simple method of storing a non-serializable custom object in a SQLite database? Or should I just byte the bullet and write really complicated setters and getters to store all of the custom object's individual custom properties broken down into their individual lists of standard properties and basically deconstruct and reconstruct the object every time it goes to and from the database?

I'm seeing mixed reports on ISerializable and derived classes. Will implementing ISerializable on a derived class from the custom object allow the derived class to be serialized? What about IXMLSerializable? Will either of these work? I just want to get some clarification if possible before I go way down the wrong rabbit hole.

Comment: Do you need to serialize only its public properties, or also its internal state?

Comment: Just its public properties I'm fairly certain

Comment: Do you need to use binary serialization or can you just store it as JSON?

Comment: As long as I can store it locally in SQLite and then retrieve and access its properties that would work. Is there a JSON method for that when the object isn't marked serializable? Would I store it as a string in SQLite?

Comment: You can use Newtonsoft, DataContractJsonSerializer, etc... typically most just use the Newtonsoft package (even Microsoft references it in some cases) to serialize/deserialize from/to json-based strings... It might be issue depending upon the performance needed, i.e. 16.6ms display refresh times when scrolling and you are trying to deserialize on the fly to feed a recyclerview or such, then stay away from any thing text-based, create custom objects that can by serialized or even better use flatbuffers to store your data, the byte array can to stored in SQLite and no de/serialization is needed.

Comment: As usual @SushiHangover you have given me a lot to chew on. Thanks.

Comment: Create a class that mimics the public properties of the class you are interested in. Then create a cloner class (with two type params, TSource and TDest). In the constructor of the cloner, walk the public readable properties of TSource and the writable properties of TDest (getting the property getters of TSource and the setters of TDest). Then build a list of TSource-getter/TDest-setter tuples. Finally, add a Clone method that takes a TSource instance & a TDest instance that walks the list & does the cloning. Once you create an instance, it's immutable, so you can use it over & over.

Comment: @mjwills it's a `TK.CustomMap.Overlays.TKPolygon` - I need to store a bunch of them to pull up on the opening of the map page and also need to run a check every five minutes to see if the device is inside any of them. I have all the logic taken care of except storing them in the database. Right now I've written setters and getters that I'm about to test. They aren't too complex but it's a lot of looping and once the collection of polygons gets pretty large it could be slow. If they work I'll add them to the question. Maybe someone will have an opinion on whether serialization is even worth it.

Comment: Or, thinking about my comment, skip the second class (and make the Cloner class have on type parameter). Just have the Clone method return a Dictionary <string, object> with the property names/values